# Unable to autowire service in AuditInterceptor which extends EmptyInterceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have my AuditInterceptor class which extends EmptyInterceptor from org.hibernate.

I am adding the interceptor to my springboot main class as a bean as below.

```
@Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factory, DataSource dataSource,
                JpaProperties properties) {
            Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            jpaProperties.putAll(properties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", hibernateInterceptor());
            return factory.dataSource(dataSource).packages("sample.data.jpa")
                    .properties((Map) jpaProperties).build();
        }

    public AuditInterceptor hibernateInterceptor() {
        AuditInterceptor auditInterceptor = new AuditInterceptor();
        return auditInterceptor;
    }
```

I have the AuditInterceptor which is trying to autowire my service class.

```
@Component
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

   private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

   @Autowired
   private IAuditMstService auditMstService;
```

When i start the springboot application i am getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 133 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please help on this issue???

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing new AuditInterceptor() try autowiring the AuditInterceptor as well.

Comment: Ya i tried doing that.But couldnt. But i resolved this by manually creating a autowireHelper which can autowire my AuditInterceptor and the service.